# Is there a way to set cluster icon by function in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, markerclusterer

Styles option in ClusterMarkers let me set options of small, medium and large icons for clustering, like:

```
var clusterStyles = [
  {
    textColor: 'white',
    url: 'path/to/smallclusterimage.png'
  },
 {
    textColor: 'white',
    url: 'path/to/mediumclusterimage.png'
  },
 {
    textColor: 'white',
    url: 'path/to/largeclusterimage.png'
  }
];
```

But is there a way to select the icon as a result of a function? For example: if cluster contains a specific marker shows small icon, large icon otherwise.

I'm using vue2-google-maps and GmapCluster component as below

```
<GmapCluster>
  <gmap-marker
    :key="index"
    v-for="(m, index) in markers"
    :position="m.position"
    :icon="m.icon"
    :animation="m.animation"
    :label="m.label"
    :title="m.title"
    :clickable="m.clickable"
    :draggable="m.draggable"
    @dragend="onDragChange($event)"
    @click="toggleInfoWindow(m, index)">
 </gmap-marker>
</GmapCluster>
```